# Does the homotopy pullback of a diagram of spaces who are homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes have the homotopy type of a CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Consider the diagram of compactly generated weakly hausdorff topological spaces:

[image]

If each space has the homotopy type of a CW-complex, when does the homotopy pullback of the diagram also have the homotopy type of a CW-complex?

Additionally, if each space ***is*** a CW-complex, when does the homotopy pullback of the diagram have the homotopy type of a CW-complex?

Sorry about the poorly formatted image. I don't know how to make tikzcd diagrams in a stack exchange post.

Thanks :)

Comment: Suppose $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $Z = \mathbb{R}^2$; I wonder what happens if the maps $X, Y \to Z$ are something like space-filling curves, or Warsaw circles...

Comment: Is it even true that the homotopy fiber has the homotopy type of a CW complex? If not, that would give a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean "pullback" as in the title or "homotopy pullback" as in the text?

Comment: @Elliot: if it doesn't have the homotopy type of a CW complex is it *really* the homotopy pullback... (I interpreted the question to be about the literal pullback as in the title.)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I meant the homotopy pullback, as in the text. I have now fixed this.

Comment: It is true. It suffices to show that the canonical homotopy pullback $W_{f,g}$ has ANR homotopy type. Replace the maps $f:X\rightarrow Z\leftarrow Y:g$ with homotopy equivalent Hurewicz fibrations between ANRs and show that the strict pullback of this new cospan is an ANR. This space is homotopy equivalent to $W_{f,g}$. (Here I'm quoting [Milnor](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-02/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4/) that a space has CW homotopy type if and only if it has ANR homotopy type.)

Comment: For @QiaochuYuan's question, take a space $X$ of non-CW type whose (unreduced) suspension is [contractible](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/119073.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ab166e08592dcfe0b0d9c85ee89f00155) and form the pushout of $CX\leftarrow X\rightarrow CX$ ($CX=$ unreduced cone). The pushout diagram of closed inclusions is a pullback, so $X$ is the pullback of $CX\rightarrow \Sigma X\leftarrow CX$. The three spaces in this triad are all contractible so of CW type, but $X$ is not.

Comment: @ Tyrone: Ok, I accept every space that has the type of a CW complex has the type of an ANR. And I am familiar with factoring maps as a homotopy equivalence and a Hurewicz fibration. But I don't understand as to how one factors the maps $f$ and $g$ in the way you suggested. Could you elaborate on this?